# getting same popup for two different buttons if we reload the page we are getting their respective popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<td style="text-align:center">@Html.ActionLink("ViewFeedback", "ViewFeedBack", "Admin", new { ID =  CAH.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-md label-warning btn-md", data_toggle="modal", data_target="#empviewModel" }) </td>


 <td style="text-align:center">@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewServiceDetails", "Admin", new { BookingID =  CAH.BookingID }, new { @class = "btn-xs btn btn-success", data_toggle="modal", data_target="#empviewModel" }) </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **data_target** Use **data-target**. Since bootstrap default attribute is **data-target**

Comment: getting error--CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Answer (score 0):

i have taken two different data_target 's then issue is fixed previously i have used same data_targe

Comment: please be specific what you want you want to load data in same modal or differ modal?

Answer (score 0):

For bootstrap 3 you should use:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Here is a trick when your modal is close all data inside modal will clear than if you reopen that modal it will comes with new data